# Google Cloud BlobListOption only iterates one level below currentDir

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I was testing some of the Cloud Storage functionality and just seen that the iterative approach only works with a level underneath the current directory?

```
Page<Blob> blobs = STORAGE_INSTANCE.list(bucket, Storage.BlobListOption.currentDirectory(),
                Storage.BlobListOption.prefix(getBucketKey(GS_SCHEMA, prefix).concat(URI_DELIMITER)));
```

Given that what `.prefix()` receives is, for example, `/dir/` and this prefix contains two nested levels such as `/dir/content/` and `/dir/content/mycontent.txt`.

If that call is executed with the previously mentioned `/dir/`, only `/dir/content/` is listed, but no more prefixes.

So, whenever I want to iterate through all the prefixes below `/dir/`, no matter what I have to reiterate `/dir/content/` so that I can see `dir/content/mycontent.txt` listed.

Is there an easy way to fix this or am I not using the API properly?

Comment: Hi @czr_RR, I am not sure about your use case. Are you trying to filter results to blobs whose names begin with `/dir/` prefix? Or are you trying to ititerate through a list of objects in a bucket? Looking forward to your response.

Comment: @sllopis thanks a lot for the quick response! I'm trying to filter results to blobs whose names begin with `/dir/`, exactly. Any blob below the given prefix, no matter how many levels after like `/dir/one/two/three/four/this_should_be_listed_too.txt`

Comment: That makes sense! I came across this [example](https://gist.github.com/hkarakose/d8f9ff78f7deb692e5302e06e8612ca6) (I have not formally tested it myself) and thought that it might come in handy for you. Can you take a look at it? Please notice that they are iterating through a list of blobs `blobs.iterateAll();`, and then doing `forEach blob`. Keep me posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `Storage.BlobListOption.currentDirectory()` parameter from the `list()` method. The following code snippet managed to display all Blobs containing a specific prefix for me:

```
Page<Blob> blobs = storage.list(bucketName, BlobListOption.prefix(prefix));
for (Blob blob : blobs.iterateAll()) {
    System.out.println(blob);
}
```